# Retrofit and Proguard error

Tags: android, gson, proguard, retrofit

I am getting the following exception when using retrofit with proguard (note, without Proguard everything works fine):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.path.to.my.model
        at com.path.to.my.callback.onResponse(Unknown Source)
        at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

My proguard file is as follows:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

The dependencies related to Retrofit that I am using are:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
```

Why is this happening? How can I go about finding the problem? Troubleshooting ideas would be very helpful.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check to make sure are have proguard configured for gson, too.  You need to make sure POJO used with gson are not obfuscated and annotations are not stripped.

*Note*: You should replace `com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }` with your model classes in the example below.

From the gson [example proguard](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) config --

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```